# how can I use mysql while mariadb preinstalled?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

my command

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

it will shows

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 38
Server version: 10.1.24-MariaDB-6 Debian 9.0

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

and when i try connect it from mysql workbench it shows
[image]

Comment: Unless you mean here to install 2 servers in parallel, you can think of MariaDB as being equal to MySQL. It will display as MariaDB or MySQL as it pleases, and the command line client is still called "mysql". To get the workbench to connect to it just follow the 4 points that are listed in the error message. Since the command line client already connected successfully to the server, I would tripplecheck point 4 (username/password). Also make sure you are using the workbench from the same computer as the MySQL/MariaDB-server is installed, otherwise "localhost" isn't the right choice.

Comment: When you ran the first command, did it ask for a password? Did you run it under system root or sudo?

Comment: @Solarflare thank you I was afraid of mariadb lol

Comment: @elenst yea it asked and it connects even if i type random password , it's same at both

Comment: Something to try:  login without a password to see if that will get you in.  Then shutdown that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MariaDB 10.1.24 on Debian 9, in all likelihood you have installed it from the default Debian repository (as opposed to MariaDB repository). Packages provided by Debian use [`unix_socket` authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/) for the local `root`, which means you cannot connect as a local `root` to the server unless you are a system `root` (either directly or via `sudo`). If you *are* a system root, you don't need a password, it is ignored.

If so, your options are:

- create another superuser, with password authentication, and configure `workbench` to use it instead of `root` -- it is by far the most accurate approach, if only it is possible to make `workbench` never use `root`;
- modify your `root@localhost` to use password authentication -- it is easy to do, but it will most likely cause problems with service scripts, startup/shutdown and such, which will also need to be updated, which, in turn, will make upgrades more complicated;
- use packages provided by MariaDB instead of those provided by Debian, as they still use password authentication for `root`. It might solve your immediate problem, but will make further maintenance harder, and besides the solution is not very reliable in a long run, as MariaDB packages can eventually switch to `unix_socket` too.

Comment: i removed mariadb completely and know i cant install mysql-server :(